# Can I add a condition to CakePHP's update statement?

Tags: php, cakephp, optimistic-locking

Since there doesn't seem to be any support for [optimistic locking in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699138/any-support-for-optimistic-locking-in-cakephp), I'm taking a stab at building a behaviour that implements it. After a little research into behaviours, I think I could run a query in the beforeSave event to check that the version field hasn't changed.

However, I'd rather implement the check by changing the update statement's WHERE clause from

```
WHERE id = ?
```

to

```
WHERE id = ? and version = ?
```

This way I don't have to worry about other requests changing the database record between the time I read the version and the time I execute the update. It also means I can do one database call instead of two.

I can see that the `DboSource.update()` method supports conditions, but `Model.save()` never passes any conditions to it.

It seems like I have a couple of options:

1. Do the check in `beforeSave()` and live with the fact that it's not bulletproof.
2. Hack my local copy of CakePHP to check for a `conditions` key in the `options` array of `Model.save()` and pass it along to the `DboSource.update()` method.

Right now, I'm leaning in favour of the second option, but that means I can't share my behaviour with other users unless they apply my hack to their framework.

Have I missed an easier option?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I went with hacking my local copy of CakePHP. I haven't looked recently to see if the latest versions of CakePHP offer any new options.

Answer (score 10):

When using `save()` to update a record, Cake expects an `id` to be present and will update only the record with this `id`.

What you're looking for is [`updateAll()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions):

> **`updateAll(array $fields, array $conditions)`**
>
> Updates many records in a single call. Records to be updated are identified by the $conditions array, and fields to be updated, along with their values, are identified by the $fields array.
>
> For example, to approve all bakers who have been members for over a year, the update call might look something like:
>
> ```
> $this_year = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('-1 year'));
>
> $this->Baker->updateAll(
>     array('Baker.approved' => true),
>     array('Baker.created <=' => "$this_year")
> );
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I know about updateAll(). I'm trying to write a behaviour that lets you keep using all the standard CakePHP patterns that go through the save() command, and just adds optimistic locking on top.

Comment: Just to clarify, the save() command currently uses a default condition that just matches the id field. I want to add a second condition that also ensures the version number hasn't changed because of another user updating the same record.