# Hibernate and Concurrency

Tags: database, performance, hibernate, concurrency, locking

I have already read the [hibernate docs about concurrency](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html) and I think, I have understood the [available locking methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking), but I am not sure how I should implement the following scenario.

Two clients F (fast) and S (slow) access the database and can modify the same objects.

Now, one additional requirement: It is critical to the application that client F performs as fast as possible.

**How would you solve the problem?**

My problem with optimistic locking:
Assume that F tries to update its changes but couldn't do this successfully, because S already updated its data. An exception (StaleObjectStateException) will be thrown from hibernate. I will catch this exception and merge the changes and try exactly the same transaction again, right? Then I don't like the case where F retries its transactions until it was successfull and so F could theoretically block a long time. Should I ignore this and hope that this condition is rare in practise? Or can I give my clients something like a database-locking-priority?

[Other users](http://blog.vacs.fr/index.php?post/2010/06/27/Fault-tolerant-EJB-interceptor%3A-a-solution-to-optimistic-locking-errors-and-other-transient-faults) can live with this problems:

*StaleObjectStateException (Optimistic Locking) ... we get 3 exceptions per 10000 calls.*

Comment: If all threads are able to complete their work (i.e. modify the database) without accessing data at the same time does your application still have issues?  It seems like it does.  It seems like you're saying C is modifying the database in a way that would cause B not to be able to complete future transactions correctly without a merge?  Maybe there's some way around that?  Is there a way to modify the environment so that concurrent modification is the only issue?

Comment: Sorry, the description was not clear: I meant with 'exception' a OptimisticLockException or StaleObjectStateException (different versions of one object) not an application exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the StaleObjectException:s and increase the priority of the thread which should be faster. StaleObjectException:s should be rare. Look into pessimistic locking if this is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that jumps out is that if you have a requirement for A+B to perform as fast as possible, you are going to get massive slow down when catching and handling exceptions.  That process is very slow.

I would have to read your post many, many more times to fully grasp what you're saying and offer a better solution but for starters, I would immediately consider not working with exceptions in this case.

Comment: I don't think that catching is that slow, but I would like to avoid the exception, of course. How should I avoid the OptimisticLockException which will be raised if two clients access a database and modify the same object?

Comment: @Karussell: I understand your question much better now, after your edit. I now see your problem domain is outside my area of expertise--our applications don't service 10s or 100s of thousands of connections/users. That being said, my first gut response was, "make it so two clients can't access a database and modify the same object." Of course, that would probably involve pessimistic locking. So, it seems, if you're going to use optimistic locking in a high-traffic environment, you almost *have to* tolerate a tiny fraction of failures.