# Testing concurrent access on Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, activerecord, concurrency, locking

This question is a follow up from this other question: [Rails 3, locking tables on an auction type engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166342/rails-3-locking-tables-on-an-auction-type-engine)

I've implemented the solution using Pessimistic Locking directly on Rails 3. Now I want to write some tests that exercise my code. I have no idea how to test concurrency problems on Rails. Any hint or gem?

The particular piece of code is very very critical and I want to be sure it is well tested.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem and have implemented a simple gem for synchronizing subprocesses using breakpoints: http://github.com/remen/fork_break

I've also documented an advanced usage scenario for rails3 at http://www.hairoftheyak.com/testing-concurrency-in-rails/

Comment: The hairoftheyak article is no longer available. Is there any chance that this answer could be updated?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's back up again.