# Is there a Web Service (WS) Standard for Optimistic Locking?

Tags: web-services, soap, web-standards, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

Is there a Web Service Standard (WS*) for Optimistic Locking / [Optimistic Concurrency Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking) (OCC) designed for interoperability?

There are a number of standards related to pessimistic concurrency control mechanisms, such as [WS-AtomicTransaction](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wsat-1.2-spec-os/wstx-wsat-1.2-spec-os.html), but as far as I can tell it doesn't provide functionality for version or timestamp handling related to optimistic locking.

I have found one article on the subject [Optimistic locking and WCF](http://geekswithblogs.net/EltonStoneman/archive/2009/04/15/managing-concurrency-over-service-boundaries.aspx), but no mayor standard. Are there such or do you know of other samples or patterns that you would like to recommend?