# Detect concurrent edits

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, concurrency

I have N (>1) web servers managed by a load balance-r and 1 instance of SQL DB as a data store in the backend. The data is read from DB, users edit it, and updated data is sent back to DB.
I'm using Linq-to-Sql. If it's a single web server, the concurrency control provided by LinqToSql is good, but with this setting, what's the good way to detect concurrent edits to the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) should do the trick. For both Pessimistic Concurrency (Locking) & Optimistic Concurrency.

See [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for a clear example and keep in mind to [clearly identify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/129397/744484) which strategy is more appropriate for you.