# How to detect if an entity is in use in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to know is there any way to know whether a record is in use with other records.

Is there any way to find it other than, by catching referential integrity exception?

I generally catch this exception and tell users no to delete or unable to delete the record.

Comment: What kind of technology/framework are you using for your CRUD operations? What type of access does your application have to system tables?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud : Linq2Sql

Comment: @DaveMarkle - the question has nothing to do with concurrency.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a query against related tables.

Comment: What If my records has been spreaded into 10-15 tables. I dont want to write it against each and every table. I want some generic way to identify

Comment: You can add a new column that will store the precalculated value if the record is referenced from other tables. You can updated the value of this column when the references are updated, so you don't have to run a heavy query on every read.

Comment: You mean to say add a column like IsInUse to track its usage. But again the question arises for its backtracking. In that case on evey delete of the record in the referenced table i have to backtrack the each and every record in that deleting record,Which is again an overkill.

Comment: It's not an overkill, it's your requirement. You want to know if the record is referenced from other table without relying on the exception. I give you the answer: query other tables. If you don't want to pay the price of querying multiple times, than cache the result in a separate column. You can store it as a number and just increment it when the relationship is added and decrement when it is removed. If the value is 0 than you know that the record is not in any relationship.

Comment: What about the System Tables where foreign keys and constraints are stored. I dont the table names nor the SPs that can used to access the data.  But an SQL DBA will know

Comment: @soadyp - System Tables will store the definition of the relationship. You will still have to execute the actual query yourself.

Comment: correct Jakub, btw i was the +1 above...I agree with you.  I was mentioning an alternative the question asker might have beyond your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure that uses the FKs in the system tables to build a custom view for each table. In each view, query all the related tables. Run the SP every time you add or remove an FK so that it updates all the views appropriately.

Problem solved.