# Adding to or retrieving from an SQL table of unique keys and values

Tags: mysql, transactions

`names` is a table that maps every unique name to an id:

```
CREATE TABLE names (
  name       VARCHAR(20)    NOT NULL,
  name_id    INT            NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (name),
  UNIQUE (name_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

If 'foobar' is already stored in `names`, I want to get its `name_id`. Otherwise I want to store it and get the `name_id` that was generated for it.

How does one do this, dealing with the possibility of two threads racing to add 'foobar'? (Note: we never delete from this table.)

With myISAM I wrote:

```
GET_LOCK('foobar');
SELECT name_id FROM names WHERE name = 'foobar';
if name wasn't found
    INSERT INTO names SET name='foobar';
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- that is, name_id
RELEASE_LOCK('foobar');
```

However, I'm very unclear about how to achieve this using transactions and row-level locking in innoDB.

**UPDATE:** mySQL requires that AUTO_INCREMENT only be used for the PK. I'm using MariaDB, which only requires that the AUTO_INCREMENT column be defined as key. Updating example accordingly.

Comment: Replace `GET_LOCK` and `RELEASE_LOCK` with `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`.

Comment: @Barmar What will happen when the second thread executes INSERT and gets a DUPLICATE KEY violation? Or is the second thread blocked at START TRANSACTION until the first thread has ended the transaction?

Comment: I think the second thread should be blocked. But try it and see.

Comment: @Barmar second thread was not blocked - got a duplicate key error.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335137/mysql-transaction-select-insert

Comment: The existing question that this duplicates is indeed the same problem, but LOCK TABLE is not the answer: we have 20 threads and the names table has 100s of millions of strings in it, and 5% of the time we're adding another. INSERT IGNORE may be the answer but it's not yet clear to me how to determine that it "Ignored" the insert due to a race condition.

Comment: Use `SELECT ROW_COUNT();`. This will be the number of rows that were inserted, so if the insert was ignored it will be `0`.

Comment: So perform the `INSERT` first. If it succeeds, return `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, otherwise do the `SELECT`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151117/discussion-between-chap-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO names (name) VALUES ('foobar');
IF ROW_COUNT() == 1
THEN SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS name_id;
ELSE SELECT name_id FROM names WHERE name = 'foobar';
END IF;
```

You don't need an explicit transaction if auto-commit is enabled, there will be an implicit transaction around the `INSERT IGNORE` query, making it atomic.

`ROW_COUNT()` will tell you whether it was able to insert the new row; it will be `1` if the name was available, `0` if a duplicate was found so no row could be inserted.

Comment: This works fine. I'm going to implement using SELECT before INSERT, however, because at this point, 95% of the time the name is already there and INSERT usually fails.

Comment: So `SELECT`, if not found `INSERT IGNORE`, then test result and `SELECT` again? Reasonable based on the preconditions.