# PHP locking vs simultaneous scripts running

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I'm using an own PHP function to lock some scripts and MySQL table data to avoid multiple data modification or insertion in case of multiple running of the script.

The function is simple, just updates a MySQL row from 0 to 1, and 1 to 0 after it's ready.

My scripts are always checking this value at the begining, and if it's 1, it waits, or quits (it depends).

This method works like a charm, except one case: If two scripts are starting precisely in the same time, it updates later that row than the other queries that, it still gets 0 back, hence they do the job two times which leads to database inconsistency. It happens very rarely, but that time it causes a huge commotion.

I'm using this solution instead of flock() because I also have to protect MySQL tables independently from PHP scripts.

What should I do? TIA

My two main functions:

```
function check( $menu ){
    global $Db;
    $lock = mysqli_query( $Db, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM lock WHERE $menu='1' AND date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 SECOND;" );
    $lockData = mysqli_fetch_object( $lock );
    mysqli_free_result( $lock );
    if ( $lockData->c > 0 ) return true; else return false;
}

function lock( $menu, $state ){
    global $Db;
    if ( $state == '1' ) $query = "UPDATE lock SET $menu='$state', date=NOW()"; else $query = "UPDATE lock SET $menu='$state'";
    mysqli_query( $Db, $query );
}
```

Comment: Are you using *SELECT FOR UPDATE* when you check if the row is 0?

Comment: you should use transactions rather than your own locking.

Comment: Please show your function.

Comment: functions are attached. What do you mean under transactions?

Comment: Transactions and `SELECT FOR UPDATE` are the solution. 100% of the code you posted should go in the bin but, even if we pretend that it _won't_, transactions and `SELECT FOR UPDATE` would still be the solution. You should try a new post about the _actual_ problem you're having. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: For a transaction see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091971/how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli/63764001#63764001 and you can find tutorials online.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The verbose procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and isn't the best option in new code, especially when it can be confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Stacking statements like that with `; else` is pretty sneaky and would make anyone trying to review this code unnecessarily frustrated. Lines are cheap. Space things out to make it readable, and the logic flow more obvious.

Comment: One trick for ["optimistic locking"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431338/optimistic-locking-in-mysql) is to just go ahead and `UPDATE` with a particular condition set that precludes it modifying an out-of-date record. This works well if conflicts are rare.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* use MySQL's "transactions" for locking for more than a few seconds.  It is not designed for such and can cause nasty hangs.  (Yes, `FOR UPDATE` is probably necessary for short cases.)

`GET_LOCK()` and its friends are a simpler alternative in MySQL.

The most efficient is to use a file system lock.  Be sure to have it in `/tmp` so that it will automatically go away after a crash.

Comment: The problem with file system lock would be the same as with my solution. Script A checks if there's lock, as there isn't it request the lock, and start it's job. In the same time script B was checking if there was lock, requested lock, and did it's job as well, simultaneously with script A.  So if they are started exactly in the same microsecond, they won't be separeted.

Comment: @user22691873 - I think flock is a "test-and-set" that fails if it cannot lock.  And it is a single step.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. But why would it be better to cause a longer hang with flock than do the same duration with sql transaction. What is the difference? (The needed precessor times for the task are the same)

Comment: I think it immediately comes back.  If the file it is locking is not used for anything else, then no one else cares.  An SQL transaction blocks others from changing any rows that you touch during before the COMMIT or ROLLBACK.