Hibernate With Only Optimistic Locking Still Generates Deadlocks
We have a business application which uses Spring Boot, Hibernate, and an underlying Oracle Database (H2 database for tests).
Users make a lot of simultaneous requests to it.
To cope with the many requests we are using optimistic locking by using a @Version field on our entities, simply retrying an operation on optimistic lock exceptions (with Spring Retry).
When either updating attributes of the same entity or using entityManager.lock(entity, OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT) in parallel,  deadlocks are detected.
What we would expect here would either be a javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException or a org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException. After all, deadlocks should only be caused by pessimistic locks. And the problem with deadlocks in Oracle DB is that they are only detected after a timeout, sometimes.
For reproducibility we have included an example which uses entityManager.lock(entity, OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT).
You can find the example here: https://github.com/ccschneidr/hibernate-deadlock-example/
The major parts of the example are

an Entity called ApplicationUser with an int attribute, annotated with @Version
a test which executes two version increments in different order, simultaneously, to simulate more complex operations where the order of modifications cannot be controlled easily:

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.LockModeType;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class DeadlockExamplesApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    Persistence persistence;

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Test
    public void testDeadlock() throws Exception {
        Integer userId1 = persistence.transactional(() ->
                userRepository.save(new ApplicationUser()).getUserid());

        Integer userId2 = persistence.transactional(() ->
                userRepository.save(new ApplicationUser()).getUserid());

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                persistence.transactional(() -> {
                    ApplicationUser applicationUser1 = userRepository.findById(userId1)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Previously created user not found"));
                    ApplicationUser applicationUser2 = userRepository.findById(userId2)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Previously created user not found"));

                    entityManager.lock(applicationUser1, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
                    entityManager.lock(applicationUser2, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);

                    return null;
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }, "thread1");

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                persistence.transactional(() -> {
                    ApplicationUser applicationUser1 = userRepository.findById(userId1)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Previously created user not found"));
                    ApplicationUser applicationUser2 = userRepository.findById(userId2)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Previously created user not found"));

                    entityManager.lock(applicationUser2, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
                    entityManager.lock(applicationUser1, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);

                    return null;
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }, "thread2");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    }
}

As far as we saw in the SQL statements, Hibernate does not explicitly lock tables/row, but the underlying database (H2 in the example, Oracle in real life) does. But this renders the 'optimistic' locks non-functional in our case.
The question is: How can we avoid deadlocks and completely rely on Hibernate's optimistic locking concept with the version number?

Looking at the same problem, Postgresql database though. Curious if someone knows the solution to this issue.

Perhaps an "old-school" solution: Lock the entities in order by ID. So if userId1 < userId2, you would lock applicationUser1 before applicationUser2 in all contexts. Notably this removes one of the necessary conditions for a deadlock to occur (circular wait), side-stepping the problem. Also of note is locks being "optimistic" won't save you from this form of deadlock.

Thanks, @Rogue. Yes, we already considered that as a workaround and it was possible in some cases and reduced the problem. Still, we have complex situations where we were not able to do that directly. And writing an abstraction layer which would do it for us seemed overkill. So, before investing a lot of time to restructure everything we want to make sure here, that it really is the only solution, because we cannot count on optimistic locking.

The other half of the deadlock solution here isn't present, but is what you normally see w/ optimistic locks: pre-emption. In other words, acquiring a lock (optimisticlly), and having that control taken away from you mid-calculation (forcing a rollback). That part about checking/rolling back can be critical to avoid a deadlock, as otherwise each "locking" will mutually own the resource and be the only one able to give it up when it says so. I'm not familiar with jakarta's implementation, but locks need to be unlocked, too.

With pessimistic/actual locks that's completely clear. But the idea of optimistic 'locks' is to do not acquire locks, in the first place. Instead, just "remember" the version number of an entity and compare the version number when committing the transaction. The problem with hibernate: when reading the version, a pessimistic read lock is acquired and kept until the end of the active transaction! So the question is: can acquiring that lock be avoided? (probably using transactions in a different way? but we need the isolation...)

When you do OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT, you're forcing an increment of the entity's version number, effectively a write. In this way, I believe you're implicitly asking for a full-lock at some point with these resources (and your suggested optimistic strategy would notice the version incrementing several times, causing several misses). Try LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC instead. If that works out, I'd suggest possibly using _FORCE_INCREMENT for writes, and not using it for reads. Notably, optimistic locking is a bad strategy when you expect misses / frequent writes.

I suppose there is a some kind of misunderstood of the main aim for optimistic locks in hibernate. The main use-case for optimistic locks is not to hold database transaction with database locks between generating view (e.g. html form) and processing user input/response after submitting data. Optimistic locks algorithm allows easy detect and handle conflicts during concurrent modification from several browsers/users. But in your case you just have two parallel database transactions with conflicting parallel updates. There is nothing to do for optimistic locks algorithm itself. You should use common approaches like update/lock ordering to avoid dead locks or retry mechanism as you mentioned.

As explained, the real-life application has a reason to use optimistic locking: exactly, handling conflict during concurrent modifications. The example reduces such a concurrent modification to the most simple conflict to have an easy reproduction. The problem that 'optimistic locks' actually result in pessimistic database locks exists in both cases (real-life and example).

Note that "optimistic" locks are still locks: no amount of optimism gets you past a "lock without a key". When you have two threads each holding a lock, refusing to give it up, and requesting the other thread's lock, you have deadlock. Optimistic locking is more beneficial for high-read/low-write environments, where the cost of locking is either often unneeded or undesired, but you face a larger performance impact on a write hit (since reads may have to be re-done). It won't solve anything to do with deadlocks, and "conflict resolution" is usually a sign you haven't designed enough safety

On the contrary, my understanding is that optimistic locking should not involve locks! cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

But for Hibernate is does, that's true. The question is: with Hibernate's optimistic locking, can I avoid the (database) locks?

Put it in another way: Optimistic locks algorithm allows you to safely split business transaction into two database transactions and have no db locks between first and second business transaction stages. The given sample test has nothing common with such approach.

So, you suggest to split operations in two transactions? That's not possible with Hibernate's LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT. Do you argue that Hibernate does not have any concept for optimistic locking in place?

LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT means database update. Database update cannot be visible in different transactions before commit. If you have two parallel updates in one row how can database or hibernate solve this issue? You can manually open two Oracle sessions without autocommit and try to update one row in parallel. The second update will wait until end of first transaction.

My conclusion is: Hibernate's optimistic locking does not pair well with transactions and concurrency. It is only suited to replace long transactions (seconds or even minutes later) by splitting them into multiple commits, keeping only the Hibernate session (and loaded entities). For highly concurrent operations standard DB locks or applications-side mutexes are needed.

The issue with the test that you have written is that it is actually creating a deadlock by interchanging the lock operations on user1 and user2.
Here is the sequence of events in your test:

In transaction T1 (first transaction), you are trying to get OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT lock on user1 and then user2.
In transaction T2 (second transaction), you are trying to get OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT lock on user2 and then user1.

Remember, OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT will actually fire an UPDATE operation in the database to update the version field (which is evident in the SQL statements in the logs), and this update operation will require a lock on that record.
Now, in your case, as we see above, when T2 tries to lock user2 to update its version, it gets to wait as user2 is locked by T1. On the other hand, T1 want to get the lock on user1 which is again locked by T2 which is already waiting for the lock of user2. So this is a classic condition that ends up in a deadlock.
To solve this, you need to write the logic in such a way, that no two transactions should request for the locks in a way (interchanged as we saw above) that they create a deadlock. In your test case, if you just interchange the entityManager.lock(..) statements in T2, you will get ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException which is expected.
EDIT:
There are 2 types of lock modes that JPA provides:

OPTIMISTIC (read)
OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT (write)

If you choose OPTIMISTIC mode, then it will not update the version in the database and thus there will be no lock required for that record, and thus your test case will pass without any error with this lock mode.
But, as I mentioned OPTIMMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT will actually need to fire the UPDATE query to update the version in the database, thus it will actually require the lock to that record for this operation.
You can read more about these lock modes here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking

Sure, if we could only read, we wouldn't have the problem. In our real-life application we have conflicting write operations though, which we cannot re-order easily. :/

But your answer seems to confirm that the optimistic locking concept of Hibernate cannot be as free from (pessimistic) locks as described, for example here

Actually, there is no concept of Optimistic locking at the database level. Any database will lock the records for update operations. Optimistic locking is a logical concept to manage locks in concurrent operations. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18806907/3709922

So, basically, that article from Wikipedia that you are referring to does not mean there will be no database locks in optimistic locking. It is just a software engineering logical concept.

That's clear. Hibernate tries to implement the concept of optimistic locking, but needs to use database technology which does not have this concept. That's the reason of the question: can we come closer to the concept of optimistic locking with Hibernate?
It seems the current direction is: no, we can't and should use other means to cope with concurrency

Well, if you are not able to manage the sequence of the operations and also your system is heavily concurrent, then the best bet in this case can be to have the transaction as small as possible. i.e. There should be only one update/insert/delete operation in one transaction. This will not be 100% deadlock-free, but as the transactions will be shorter, the chances of deadlock will be minimised by a certain level. In this case, you would need extra logic to rollback the operations that are already committed, if anything goes wrong.

I could even suggest having the mutex locks in your Java code on the object/entity that you are working on. Example: 1. Select all the users for which you want to execute any operation 2. Generate some unique checksum using those userIds 3. Apply mutex lock on this unique checksum 4. Start the transaction and do all the operations for those users 5. Release the mutex lock once the transaction is committed.

Yeah, we need to come up with a much more complex locking concept it seems. In our real-life application deadlocks are between different types of entities (not two users, but a document and a user etc.). Also, different type of operations. That's why ordering, delaying or splitting operations is hard.

Yeah, I think you should use a mixed approach of shorter transactions and mutexs to handle concurrency in your application.

The sibnick's answer is the only correct answer for the particular question, however, I would like to add my own "two cents"...
The fundamental problem is JPA locking model has nothing in common with capabilities provided by ~current DBs and developer's expectations, yeap, Optimistic Locking does work in very specific case when our goal is to prevent loosing changes caused by concurrent modifications of the same entity, however in other cases it is actually an evil, rather than good. Let's elaborate:

EntityManager#lock(entity, OPTIMISTIC) call assumes that upon transaction commit (yeah, spring's @Transactional issues commit every time, regardless whether we have performed modifications or not), JPA engine issues something like select version from tbl where id = :id (please check EntityVerifyVersionProcess), and I have no idea what do they expect to find out there: if we work with IS >=RR, such select reveals nothing, in case of RC IS, sometimes it may reveal inconsistencies, but sometimes it won't - here I would prefer to operate with always and never quantifiers, rather than sometimes. So, EntityManager#lock(entity, OPTIMISTIC) call is broken by design (I would actually prefer something like select id from tbl where id = :id and version = :version for share there, however I'm not sure about consequences)
EntityManager#lock(entity, OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT) is even worse: it causes readers to modify DB state (please check EntityIncrementVersionProcess), so, basically, readers do compete with other readers, which is actually a nonsense (someone may fail with OptimisticLockException, someone will get a deadlock like in your case, both cases do lead to the same outcome: competing transaction gets rolled back and you need to reiterate it somehow) - nobody being sane would design such application. The only case when such call could be useful is the following: you have a quite complex domain model and you are modifying child entities without modifying the root one and you would like to "notify" others that the "whole state" of root entity has been promoted. Basically, it's effect is the same as you would add something like modifyDate to root entity and update it upon every business transaction completion - the actual problem is JPA "prefer" to not persist non-dirty states, so, OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT actually looks like a dirty hack in this situation
EntityManager#lock(entity, PESSIMISTIC_READ(WRITE)) does not work properly with @Versionable entities: upon locking JPA engine tries to check whether inmemory version of entity is consistent with DB version and if not it fails the transaction. Perfect, "read" calls may fail the transaction - JPA engine does believe it is responsible for business logic. However, in the most cases my locking pattern would look like lock & refresh, and, unfortunally, instead of just calling something reliable like EntityManager#lockAndRefresh(entity, PESSIMISTIC_READ) I need to write something like select 1 from tbl where id = :id and version = :version for share/update and check the result returned.


Got same issue, but after upgrading hibernate the problem was resolved, they problably patched it.

hibernate 6.4.4 - deadlock when using optlock_force_increment
hibernate 6.6.0 - ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException (no
deadlocks UPDATE: less deadlocks :)

UPDATE: After further testing sadly even in 6.6.0 Im getting deadlocks sometimes. It is non-deterministic for now, If I find a cause I will update this post.

updating Hibernate to 6.6.0.Final in the example does not change the behavior of the test

The problem in the question is not related to the version of any dependency. It is actually linked with the lock mode that we are trying to get on the records and their sequence. Check my answer.
