# Is there update action executed at the exactly time(not overlaping) in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I attended an interview today and came across an interesting question:

What problem, if two request with UPDATE action will execute concurrently in sql?. I knew we have optimistic locking and pessimistic locking approach to [resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking) this. I am just completely stuck with this idea in my head!

1. **Optimistic locking**: During this time, when i check the **timestamp** (where mytimestamp = oldtimestamp). What happens if request 1 and request 2 will reach to this point at the exact same time (I mean completely exact)? => i am stuck at this point!
2. **Pessimistic locking** : (In Exclusive lock mode)

   2.1. When the client looses connection with server, the lock still exist in Db and other client cannot do anything => How to resolve this kind of issue?

   2.2. And also when requests come and acquire the same lock( At **read** moment ) at the exact same time => what happen in this case?

Please advice on this problem because i am very interested in the solution on how to resolve this in real time scenario.

If you have any question, please add to the comment section.

**Edit:**

I also refer [this article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/how-sql-server-handles-concurrent-requests). See my attachment for more clear.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: 2 thiings arriving at the exact same time is not possible.

Comment: Which DB it was , as in oracle/teradata/SQL server  to avoid locking there are rules for locks and if the client does lost a connection with the server does not lock. Eg in SQL server if you are doing update using select , use NO LOCK option in your select so that it will not lock your table..etc

Comment: eg for 2.2 , multiple read can happen at same time without lock . Also read can be done with write going on the same table  [Dirty Read]

Comment: thank for your comment but i just wanna clarify it! i think this situation still exist but rarely, i also reference this post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9813/how-sql-server-handles-concurrent-requests

Comment: I think you read about oracle locking here ...http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm

Comment: by the way you didnt mentioned the db as this may happen with us in our next interview...:)

Comment: Like i mentioned in title => this is question on SQL. Thank you.

Comment: If you got any help from my comments accept my answer...:)

Comment: "this is question on SQL" doesn't help when determining the DB engine. You just specified the *language* (which is actually irrelevant to your question). If you mean MS SQL server, use the sql-server tag. Oracle, MySQL, Postgres... all of those also use SQL, and there's plenty of differences to be had.

Comment: Is there any advice?