# SQL: Select first and update - for concurrent users

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, priority-queue

TL;DR:
I want a table in my database to act as an priority queue (Here a min-queue on `ID`), are there any free (for commercial use) DBMS that can solve my problem? And how would a query look like?

I want to have many concurrent users to select a single row from a table, e.g. I have the table

```
+------+-------+--------+------------+
| ID   | Col 1 | Col 2  | Processed  |
+------+-------+--------+------------+
| 1000 | data  | data   | False      |
+------+-------+--------+------------+
| 1001 | data  | data   | False      |
+------+-------+--------+------------+
| 1002 | data  | data   | False      |
+------+-------+--------+------------+
```

and if I have 3 users, I want to do atomic `SELECT` and `UPDATE`, such that the first query returns `Col 1` and `Col 2` from the row with the lowest `ID` and marks `Processed` as `True`, such that the the next query would return the row with `ID = 1001`.

The table is expected to be small, i.e. at most 100,000 rows and the queue is expected to be emptied in about 8 hours (around 3-4 queries per second, peak might be around 50 queries in a single second). I am used to PostgreSQL/MySQL and have used MongoDB briefly.

How should I design my system to cope with this? How would a query look like? Would a table lock noticable?

Comment: You should look into [pessimistic concurrency](http://stackoverflow.com/a/129397/3410196)

Comment: If you're not using SQL Server you should remove the tag.  SQL Server based answers are unlikely to help you.

Comment: "re there any free (for commercial use) DBMS that can solve my problem? " is not normally a question we answer. However, I would think you can use any DB that has row/document level locking can you not?

Comment: @Sammaye I suspect that I can (one of the three mentioned), but it might be that one was preferred over the others. If there was a DBMS that was designed for exactly this, I would most likely change to that - if it was free for commercial use.

Comment: So what you want is a work query? There are applications for that, please don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `PostgreSQL` should be a good candidate for this.

Some interesting pointers:

- (9.5 only) [SKIP ROW LOCKED](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-5-feature-highlight-skip-locked-row-level/)
- [ROW-LEVEL-LOCKS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS)
- [SELECT FOR UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html)

Unless I am missing something, each thread does a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` (with `SKIP ROW LOCKED`) so that it picks the first non-locked row and locks it for everyone else, processes it, and flags it / deletes it once done.

Comment: That was a feature that I did not know. It seems like `MySQL` can also be used, however I am not sure how to handle the `SKIP ROW LOCKED` in this case. `PostgreSQL` it is then!