# Does closing DBI handle release lock from postgres database

Tags: java, postgresql, dbi

I am trying to write a web application that will run on multiple servers but share a single database for financial transactions.

In simple terms i want to transfer money from account A to B. But there could be multiple requests to transfer money from the same account.

The balance can never be negative, hence i decided to use SELECT FOR UPDATE to fetch the balance to lock the row.

I am using JDBI for a connection to the database : http://jdbi.org/

The code flow is as follows :

Controller :

```
DBI dbi = new DBI(datasource);

.....
getAccountBalance();

....

transfer()
```

Here is the DOA part

```
public int getAccountBalance(String id) {
        Handle h = dbi.open();
        try{
            return h.createQuery("SELECT balance FROM accounts " +
                                " WHERE id=:id FOR UPDATE;")
                    .bind("id", id)
                    .mapTo(Integer.class)
                    .first();
        } finally {
            h.close();
        }
    }
```

The DAO returns the balance, i run a balance check to see if the transfer can be made and then call another method to perform the transfer.

```
public void transfer(String fromAccountId, String toAccountId, int transferAmount) {
        Handle h  = dbi.open();
        try{
            h.begin();
            h.createStatement("UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - :transferAmount WHERE id = :fromAccountId")
                .bind("fromAccountId", fromAccountId)
                .bind("transferAmount", transferAmount)
                .execute();
            h.createStatement("UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + :transferAmount WHERE id = :toAccountId")
                .bind("toAccountId", toAccountId)
                .bind("transferAmount", transferAmount)
                .execute();
            h.commit();
        } finally {
            h.close();
        }
    }
```

My question is if i close the handle in `getAccountBalance()` will it release the lock on the row it selected ? if that's the case how do i hold the lock ? I am new to DBI. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually released before the `h.close()`, at `h.commit()`. Row locks are not held beyond commit.

If you need locks that are held past commit you can use advisory locks, but they're a bit awkward, and not something I'd recommend for something like this.

Otherwise read up on [pessimistic vs optimistic locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). See also [Optimistic vs. Pessimistic locking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129329/398670) .

Comment: I create the lock in method A, but commit in method B. will that still hold the lock ? sorry if i did not explain it properly earlier.

Comment: @AmitVig I don't know what your `dbi` object is, or what  its `open` method does, so it's kind of hard to answer that. The point is that *a lock is held until the transaction that acquired it commits*. If your first method still held the lock, and your second method is called within a separate DBI connection, it would just block on the first transaction's lock indefinitely. Or if you call it within the same open transaction on the same connection, it'd issue a warning about a transaction already being open, but otherwise work ok.

Comment: so *at a wild guess*, `getAccountBalance` isn't starting an explicit transaction, so it's autocommitted. The lock is thus not held past the return of the statement. But that's making some guesses about what your transaction boundaries are.

Comment: i absolutely forgot to mention what DBI is, i am using JDBI from http://jdbi.org/ to help with the database connections.

Comment: @AmitVig So you need to look up transaction management in jdbi then

Comment: I've figured out an approact with using the @Transaction annotation. This annotation makes the entire set of sql i want to run in a single transaction and gets me what i am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @AmitVig Consider writing your own answer with JDBI specifics