# Block mysql record while editing by a client

Tags: php, mysql

**Introduction:**

1- I am not looking for a code solution.

2- I am only asking for a way of thinking (algorithm)

**Problem Description:**

1- I have a `mysql` database running on a server.

2- The database will be accessed by several clients at the same time using a webapp powered by `php`

3- If client `A` opens a record `recordIdX` within the webapp, it will be displayed in correspondent `html input fields`, and the client will have the time to modify those values before submitting the `form`.

4- The problem that might happen is when another client `B` opens the same `recordIdX`, modifies it, and `update` the database before client `A` finishes the update..

**Question:**

What is the best way to prevent this conflict ?

Comment: Whatever you end up choosing, you need to consider carefully: what if client `A` opens the record, but then never edits/closes it?

Comment: "I am not looking for a code solution." they why is the tag PHP included?

Comment: I would consider something like hashing the record and putting that in a hidden field. Then when saving, check to see if the record still has the same hash. If not, then someone else edited it and you need to do some conflict resolution.

Comment: "What is the best way to prevent this conflict ?" -> Use InnoDB as table engine  and include FOR UPDATE into the select `SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE .... FOR UPDATE` this way the record can only be updated by the first client who has openend it with `FOR UPDATE`

Comment: This type of question is both too broad and possibly opinion-based. I would post this on DB exchange instead https://dba.stackexchange.com/ - You will get a better response there.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, why don't you convert your comment related to InnoDB to an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One webapp I developed had a similar requirement. This is how I did it:

Tables wich should be 'lockable' had a `accessId` column. `accessId` was a foreign key to the `access` table wich had some relevant columns for example: isLocked, isLockedByUserId, lastModificationDate, ...

This might be interesting too: [Optimistic vs. Pessimistic locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking)

Comment: still prone to race conditions.. what if both clients request the same record at the same time and the database didn't had time to update the lockable record intime.

Comment: @RaymondNijland pessimistic locking would prevent race conditions

Comment: Best option the topicstarter has is to use InnoDB and `FOR UPDATE` and let the database handle the locking..

Comment: 1 or 2 additional fields (lock guid,timestamp) can be used instead of another table, but otherwise this is the only solution. `FOR UPDATE` has to be used to guarantee atomic locking.

Comment: @Vatev, I actually followed your opinion with just one field `isopen` .. I don't need more information... if it is set to 0, set it to 1 and open record... otherwise, echo message that field already in use...

Comment: @mlwn how do you tell which client has the lock and who has to wait? Also you will need a timestamp and a lock timeout. Otherwise the record can (and will) become locked permanently after a network failure, crash etc.

Comment: @Vatev, I already have another variable with the client id which is logged in. So, if the field `islocked` is `0`, nobody is using the field.. otherwise, I put the id of the client in this field `e.g. 4` for client id `4`... any user who wants to use the field will get a message that the field is locked by client id 4. If it was locked after network failure, client id 4 can still open the field and close it normally which will unlock it... that's basically more than what i need..