# Active record's find_by return nil when there is valid record exist in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mysql2, actioncable

I am facing one issue on production site, we using action cable, Sometime the below code inside the channel file not working when there is race condition.

```
article = Article.find_by_name("cat")
```

The above code sometime returning nil even there is valid record exist. Don't know how to fix these kind of issues. I just assumed it may happen on the race condition. Also reviewed the production log file and MYSQL log, there is no abnormal things, all looks good.

We using below version,

```
rails - 5.2.3
Aciverecord - 5.2.3
mysql2 - 0.5.2
actioncable - 5.2.3
```

Database.yml is below

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: root

development:
  <<: *default
  database:  localdb 
  
test:
  <<: *default
  database: xipk_test

production:
  <<: *default
  host: <%= ENV['Host'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['database'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['username'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['password'] %>
```

article channel

```
class ArticleChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def subscribed    
    stream_from "article_#{uuid}_channel"
    name = params["article[name]"]
    article = Article.find_by_name(name)
    if !article.nil?
      response_code = 404
    else
      response_code = 200
    end
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "article_#{uuid}_channel", {
      article_response: article_response,
      response_code: "#{response_code}"
    }
  end

end
```

article model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :title, :case_sensitive=> false
  validates_presence_of :address
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :request_histories, :dependent => :destroy
  default_scope { order('updated_at DESC') }
  before_create :generate_guid, unless: :guid?
  after_save :update_dashboard
  

  def self.default_scope
    where("is_test = ? AND (test_mode = ?  OR test_mode IS NULL)", false, "ABB")
  end

  def generate_guid
    self.guid ||= SecureRandom.uuid
  end


  def check_witl_null_value(c_val)
    act_val = self.send("#{c_val}")
    act_val if act_val!= "null"
  end 

end
```

Any solution for these kind of issues?

Comment: You can try pessimistic locking the row, then there is no more race conditions. The database will have to wait the lock is released to read the data. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html Also use locking sparingly to avoid deadlocks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking

Comment: Your question is very hard to follow, what makes you think it's a race condition?  When you say "even there is valid record exist" - how are you checking/confirming that?  The `default_scope` is the glaringly obvious candidate for a problem here and yet you never commented on it, nor confirmed that it wasn't the cause of the issue.  Please edit your question to demonstrate the problem more obviously, copy/paste from a `rails console` sessions showing the checks you're doing to confirm your assumptions.