# Junit5 Optimistic locking exception

Tags: junit5, spring-test, optimistic-locking

I have nearly 1000 test classes coded using spring boot junit5. These run in parallel on Jenkins. Since my 6 test classes use the same table, I am getting optimistic lock errors and I could not find a solution.

**Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [systems.hr.Employee#118677280]**

I get an error message like this.

what can i do for this issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimistic vs. Pessimistic locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking)

Comment: Unfortunately :(