# Concurrent Data Change exception

Tags: guidewire

What is optimistic locking approach and how we can achieve it to resolve concurrent Data Change exception.

Trying to know the approach to resolve concurrent Data Change exception. Right now I don't have this issue, but I faced it some time back when I worked in conversion project. We used to get it when we are loading policies to PC

Comment: Please make sure to provide more details in your questions, asking about a specific issue or use case, otherwise, moderators tend to downvote theoretical questions like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Optimistic locking is not something one needs to implement explicitly. Guidewire already uses it by implementing entity instance versioning in all database transactions. Concurrent data change exceptions can occur when multiple users or processes are trying to update or commit the same entity row to the database. Guidewire protects entity instances from concurrent access through a `BeanVersion` property that exists on all versionable entities. When a versionable entity instance is loaded into a bundle, the application loads the `BeanVersion` number and stores it with the data. Whenever a bundle commits, Guidewire checks this `BeanVersion` property in each entity instance with the latest version in the database. Then it is confirmed that the cached entity instance is up to date. If the version numbers match, the commit can proceed. If the version numbers do not match, the entire commit attempt fails for the bundle. If a change for an object relies on a dirtily read database row, it is unsafe to commit this recent change and thus the bundle gets rolled back ensuring atomicity. This strategy to avoid conflicts and unwanted modifications is called [optimistic locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking).
Here is a simple example to describe the same with a sequence of events:

```
Consider an entity with a text field Name = Unknown, BeanVersion = 0
User 1 starts updating Name = A, BeanVersion = 1
User 2 starts updating Name = B, BeanVersion = 1 
User 1 completes and commits the transition and BeanVersion = 1
User 2 tries to commit the transaction but is prevented from doing so due to conflicting BeanVersion.
User 2 is shown a ConcurrentDataChangeException and forced to refresh his version of the entity.
User 2 updates Name = B, BeanVersion = 2
```

So ideally, there should not be an intent to handle or override a concurrent data change since it's an essential feature that prevents unwanted and ambiguous modifications. However, if you are seeing it too frequently, it can suggest that multiple processes have transaction bundles open on the same entity and it is more likely when batch processes or web services are trying to operate on an entity row at the same time when a user has it open on the screen. It can also come up due to a bigger design flaw when some long-running transactions or bundles stay open for a long period maybe because they're waiting for a response or acknowledgment from another service or dependent on other complex database reads that are slow to process. The easiest way to prevent this is by ensuring that bundles are opened only when you are ready to commit data and are not doing additional processing that can be done outside the bundle. Batch processes should be chunked with regular commits instead of relying on a single large transaction.

Guidewire also supports pessimistic locking by using something called `ReentrantLock` but it should never be used unless you have an indispensable requirement to use one. This avoids concurrent data change but can give rise to a plethora of other issues like deadlocks and slowness and the kind of problems you need to call Guidewire architects for.

Comment: Most of Ahbijays remarks are excellent.  I would be even more careful than he suggests with ReentrantLocks.  These are not really database locks, they are based on java locks.  If you are running in a cluster or are not using the same set of objects on which the locks were set to do the database update the lock will be ineffective.

Comment: Thanks, Edgar. Totally agree with you and there are no locks possible at the database layer as insurance suite apps require the database isolation level to be “Read Committed Snapshot” which uses snapshots of tables to prevent dirty reads instead of row locks.

Answer (score 1):

The ootb behavior is that a concurrent data change will fail the commit attempt and user action and force the user (in a UI-driven scenario) to re-apply their changes and commit again.  For an automated scenario the expectation is that the action would fail and retry in some automated fashion.

It is feasible to catch the exception and retry "in-line" but that's going to depend on the complexity of the scenario and how feasible it is to retry in the transaction after reloading the beans to get the latest version.  It's generally safest to externally retry vs retrying in-line but I have seen cases where this was implemented to handle some specific cases.